# Display countdown to closing time of current day / opening time next day

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i'd like to show a countdown in hours:minutes:seconds to the closing time (if opened) or to the opening time (next day when closed). How can I do this in html?

Comment: If what is opened or closed? Please be more specific and please make an attempt to write some code.

Comment: you need javascript to do this, not html, hth

Comment: A shop is opened from monday until saturday from 10:00 - 19:00. Sunday its closed. I'd like to implement a countdowncounter on the website for visitors. for example. We are *opened* for another *2:27:30* (if opened) OR We are *closed and will open in* *2:27:30* (if closed)

Comment: definitely need to use javascript - will you need to take timezones into consideration?

Comment: No only Europe-Amsterdam

Comment: This question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. You are asking us to write code for you, which is not how Stack  Overflow works. We are happy to help with code you have written and are having problems with. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for more information about what to ask and what not to ask.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var $timer = $('#timer');
  var $countdownText = $('#countdownText');
  var now = moment();
  var openingToday = moment({
    hour: 8
  });
  var closingTime = moment({
    hour: 17
  });
  var openingTime = moment({
    year: now.year(),
    month: now.month(),
    date: now.date() + 1,
    hour: 8
  });
  if (now.diff(openingToday) < 0) {
    $timer.countdown({
      until: openingToday._d
    });
    $countdownText.addClass('closed');
  } else if (now.diff(closingTime) < 0) {
    $timer.countdown({
      until: closingTime._d
    });
    $countdownText.addClass('opened');
  } else {
    $timer.countdown({
      until: openingTime._d
    });
    $countdownText.addClass('closed');
  }
});
```

```css
#countdownText span {
  display: none;
}

#countdownText.opened .close,
#countdownText.closed .open {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countdown/2.0.2/jquery.plugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countdown/2.0.2/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countdown/2.0.2/jquery.countdown.css" />
<div id="countdownText">
  <span class="open">Opening in</span>
  <span class="close">Closing in</span>
</div>
<div id="timer"></div>
```